# Multi table check constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, constraints

Is it possible to add a check constraint based on criteria in two other tables? I have three tables: collections, sessions, and session_detail. My goal is to prevent more than one occurrence of a structure into session_detail from the same collection and with the same session type.

Applying the function that I have so far to the *sessions* table checks for unique collections and sessions, but not for unique structures.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[checkSessionType](@collection as varchar(max), @type as varchar(max))  
RETURNS int  
AS   
BEGIN  
DECLARE @sessionType varchar(max) 

SELECT @sessionType = case when @type = 'R' then @type When @type = 'T' then @type END
DECLARE @retval int

SELECT @retval = COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT a.structure_id, b.collection, b.session_type 
        FROM session_detail a 
        INNER JOIN sessions b ON a.session_id = b.session_id 
        WHERE b.collection = @collection 
        AND b.session_Type = @sessionType 
) AS tempResults
RETURN @retval  
END;
```

This is a simplified version of what the tables look like:

```
collections(collection)
sessions(session_id, collection, session_type)
session_detail(detail_id, session_id, structure_id)
```

So how would I allow a structure to be in the same collection more than once as long as it has a different session type? I could do this with a trigger but I'd prefer a constraint.

Comment: Can you script out your tables to SQL and include the foreign keys and unique keys and then include them in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an indexed view, for example:

```
CREATE VIEW v_session_detail
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT sd.structure_id, s.collection, s.session_type
FROM dbo.session_detail sd
INNER JOIN dbo.sessions s ON s.session_id=sd.session_id
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_v_session_detail ON v_session_detail(structure_id, collection, session_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have control as check constraint:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[checkSessionType](@session_id as INT, @structure_id as INT)  
RETURNS int  
AS   
BEGIN  

DECLARE @retval int

SELECT @retval = COUNT(*)
FROM sessions a 
INNER JOIN session_detail b ON a.session_id = b.session_id 
WHERE b.structure_id = @structure_id 
AND b.session_id = @session_id
GROUP BY a.collection, a.session_type, b.structure_id

RETURN @retval  
END

GO

ALTER TABLE [session_detail] ADD CONSTRAINT ck_session_detail CHECK ([dbo].[checkSessionType](session_id, structure_id) <= 1)
```

Similarly you would need to have check also on `sessions` table. To do so you can create another function just for purpose of checking `sessions` table or customize previous one to fit both cases:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[checkSessionType](@session_id as INT, @collection as INT, @structure_id as INT)  
RETURNS int  
AS   
BEGIN  

DECLARE @retval int

SELECT @retval = COUNT(*)
FROM sessions a 
INNER JOIN  session_detail b ON a.session_id = b.session_id 
WHERE b.structure_id = ISNULL(@structure_id, b.structure_id)
AND a.collection = ISNULL(@collection, a.collection)
AND b.session_id = @session_id
GROUP BY a.collection, a.session_type, b.structure_id

RETURN @retval  
END

GO

ALTER TABLE [sessions] ADD CONSTRAINT ck_sessions CHECK ([dbo].[checkSessionType](session_id, collection, null) <= 1)
ALTER TABLE [session_detail] ADD CONSTRAINT ck_session_detail CHECK ([dbo].[checkSessionType](session_id, null, structure_id) <= 1)
```

Comment: We should point-out that this check constraint does not verify any modifications done by updating the columns in the `session` table (it is checked only when inserting or updating a row in the `session_detail` table).

Comment: Jan, your function checks if the structure exists in the session more than once, but I need to check if the structure exists in the same collection and session type more than once.The collection can have more than one session of the same type, but a structure cannot exist in different sessions of the same type in the same collection.  If I add a constraint to the sessions table it doesn't receive the structure_id, and if I add a constraint to the session_detail it doesn't receive the collection.

Comment: @jshort right, that's why you need to join between them. Unique combination is: `structure_id, collection, session_type`, just like in Razvan's answer.

Comment: @JanMuncinsky thanks for your patience and expertise! Can you explain what the constraint on the sessions table would look like? Would that one need structure_id passed to it? To me it looks like I'd have to pass structure_id to it also but I get an "Invalid column name 'structure_id'" error when I do.